# Could not resolve dependency: peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0" from @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@3.0.3 node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react

Tags: reactjs, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csvmz.png)

Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0" from @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@3.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react
npm ERR!   @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@"^3.0.3" from the root project

Answer (score 1):

This is dute to npm not working for new versions in your project.
You have to force install the npm and node.
Try the commands:

1. `npm insatll -f@ version that exists`
2. `npm install -f`